# Collider triggers firing on launch

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a "zone", with four borders; north, east, south and west. On these borders, I have 2d colliders, like this :

[image]

So, on a zone, I would have four instances of this, for each border. In the script for GridBorderController, I have this :

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == Const.TAG_PLAYER)
    {
        print("enter " + gridBorderSide.ToString());
        /*var pos = new Vector3(20, 20, 0);
        var zoneInstance = Instantiate(this, pos, Quaternion.identity, this.transform);
        var tileMaker = zoneInstance.transform.GetChild(0);
        var terrainDrawer = tileMaker.GetComponent<TerrainDrawer>();
        print(terrainDrawer.sprites.Length);*/
    }

}
```

When I launch the game, I create an instance of this zone, and this is what I get in my console :

[image]

This is how I start the controller :

```
void Start()
{
    boxCollider2D = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    terrainDrawer = GetComponentInParent<TerrainDrawer>();
    collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();

    collider.enabled = false;

    var gridRadius = terrainDrawer.gridRadius;
    float borderOffset = borderWidth / 2;



    switch (gridBorderSide)
    {
        case GridBorderSide.North:
        case GridBorderSide.South:
            {
                boxCollider2D.size = new Vector2(gridRadius/2 , borderWidth);
                if(gridBorderSide == GridBorderSide.North)
                {
                    boxCollider2D.transform.position += new Vector3(0, (gridRadius / 4) - (borderOffset));
                }
                else
                {
                    boxCollider2D.transform.position -= new Vector3(0, (gridRadius / 4) - (borderOffset));
                }
                break;
            }
        case GridBorderSide.East:
        case GridBorderSide.West:
        {
                boxCollider2D.size = new Vector2(borderWidth, gridRadius / 2);
                if (gridBorderSide == GridBorderSide.East)
                {
                    boxCollider2D.transform.position += new Vector3((gridRadius / 4) - (borderOffset), 0 );
                }
                else
                {
                    boxCollider2D.transform.position -= new Vector3((gridRadius / 4) - (borderOffset), 0);
                }
                break;
            }
    }

    collider.enabled = true;

}
```

When I walk over the collider with my player, it does fire as well, so I know that part works, but can anyone explain the me why the triggers fire immediately on launch?

Comment: Are you sure you dont have additional colliders on the player that expand out in a large direction? or tht you dont instantiate the colliders where the player is?

Comment: @BugFinder The player does contain a collider, but no events on that collider. I double checked now, and the hitbox around the player is not large, ie, expanding over the other hit boxes of my border colliders. I -do- instantiate the collider of the border on the player, but you will notice that I disable the collider before I set the 
 position, which I assumed will disable the trigger as well

Comment: Its not entirely clear but it really sounds like its the instantiate that makes it appear with the collider, and thats where the messages come from

Comment: @BugFinder, from what I'm experiencing, I'm inclined to agree with you. It feels like the borders are instantiated on the player, triggers fire, and then resized. I'll see if I can instantiate them in a different location, and see if it makes a difference